# Replace number in variable with another variable in for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, count, var

I'm trying to produce 25 variables from $day1Txt through to $day2Txt.

How do I turn the '1' in the variable `$day1Txt` into the variable `$i`?

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 25; $i++) { 

        $day1Txt = echo call_user_func('Day_'.$i.'_Offer', 'EMAIL_OFFER'); 

}
```

I've made an attempt myself but it white screens...

```
  ${'day'.$i.'Txt'} = echo call_user_func('Day_'.$i.'_Offer', 'EMAIL_OFFER');
```

Comment: Please expand on your question, what are you trying to achieve? If it is in a loop it will be keep changing until the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Use an array instead where `$i` is used as index?

Comment: I just removed the echo and it hasn't errored, but I dont know if the variables are stored yet... so this probably isn't an answer.

Comment: It’s possible to get the variable name and then you could split the string (or you could hardcode the ints by using a `for` as you tried to), but for all sanity, you really really should use arrays instead. There is no reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you(remove `echo`).

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 25; $i++) {

        ${"day".$i."Txt"} =  call_user_func('Day_' . $i . '_Offer', 'EMAIL_OFFER');
    }
```

If you want to see what all variables are there in your function use `get_defined_vars()`.

See deme [here](https://eval.in/464306)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 25; $i++) { 

        ${"day".$i."Txt"} = call_user_func('Day_'.$i.'_Offer', 'EMAIL_OFFER'); 

}
```

It's called [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) ie a variable name which can be set and used dynamically

Comment: that echo is ruining the party

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Its Ok. Time to delete comments